# Trigger props.onChange() when onBlur() on TextField

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onchange

I'm building a component NumberField that will remove the 0 when clicked (onFocus), allowing the user to enter a number from an empty field, and will put back a 0 when focus is out (onBlur) and the field is empty.

I would like to call the onChange function from the props when the onBlur is triggered.

```js
import * as React from 'react'

import {
    TextField,
    TextFieldProps
} from '@material-ui/core'

const NumberField: React.FC<TextFieldProps> = (props: TextFieldProps) => {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState<string>(`${props.value}`)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setState(`${props.value}`)
    }, [props.value])

    function onChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        setState(event.target.value)
    }

    function onFocus() {
        if (state === '0')
            setState('')
    }

    function onBlur() {
        if (state === '')
            setState('0')

        const value = parseFloat(state || '0')
        if (value !== props.value) {
            // call props.onChange
        }
    }

    return (
        <TextField
            type="number"
            onChange={onChange}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            {...props}
        />
    )
}

export default NumberField
```

The reason why I want to "simulate" an onChange event call is because I'm using Formik:

```js
                    <NumberField
                        fullWidth
                        name="unit"
                        label="Unit"
                        value={formik.values.unit}
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        error={formik.touched.unit && Boolean(formik.errors.unit)}
                        helperText={formik.touched.unit && formik.errors.unit}
                    />
```

The signature of formik.handleChange is:

```
(property) handleChange: {
    (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>): void;
    <T_1 = string | React.ChangeEvent<any>>(field: T_1): T_1 extends React.ChangeEvent<any> ? void : (e: string | React.ChangeEvent<any>) => void;
}
```

I need a "fake" React.ChangeEvent. Any ideas? I already tried a lot of things found on SO (including useRef, dispatchEvent, and other stuffs), but not working and very old. Perhaps things have changed since...

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the direct question "how to simulate a trigger event", but rather a alternative solution in the case you're using Material-UI & Formik.

```js
import * as React from 'react'

import {
    TextField,
    TextFieldProps
} from '@material-ui/core'

type NumberFieldProps = TextFieldProps & {
    setValue: (value: number) => void
}

const NumberField: React.FC<NumberFieldProps> = (props: NumberFieldProps) => {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState<string>(`${props.value}`)
    const { value, ...restProps } = props

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setState(`${props.value}`)
    }, [props.value])

    function onChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        setState(event.target.value)
    }

    function onFocus() {
        console.log('focus')
        if (state === '0')
            setState('')
    }

    function onBlur() {
        console.log('blur')
        if (state === '')
            setState('0')

        const value = parseFloat(state || '0')
        if (value !== props.value) {
            props.setValue(value)
        }
    }

    return (
        <TextField
            type="number"
            value={state}
            onChange={onChange}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            {...restProps}
        />
    )
}

export default NumberField
```

```js
const MaterialForm: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const formik = useFormik({
        ...
    })

    return (
        ...
                <Grid item style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                    <NumberField
                        fullWidth
                        name="factor"
                        label="Factor"
                        value={formik.values.factor}
                        setValue={(value) => formik.setFieldValue('factor', value)}
                        error={formik.touched.factor && Boolean(formik.errors.factor)}
                        helperText={formik.touched.factor && formik.errors.factor}
                    />
        ...
    )
}

export default MaterialForm
```

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void

I would still be interested to know how it is possible to emulate a onChange event  in React nowadays !!